# Route based on string in array

Tags: node.js, express

If I have an array like:

```
var users = [
    { name: 'joe', info : 'this man's name is joe'},
    { name : 'betty', info : 'this woman's name is betty'}
];
```

and route like:

```
app.get('/test/:person', loadUser, function(req, res) {
   if (!err) {
      res.send(req.user.info);
   }
   else {
      res.redirect('/');
   }
})
```

how do I set up the `loadUser` middleware so that if the `:person` param is equal to one of the names in the array, the page is loaded with its respective info. However, if the `:person` entered isn't in the array, it simply redirects to another page.

So far what I have is:

```
function loadUser(req, res, next){
    for(var i= 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if ( req.params.gg == users[i].id ) {
    req.user = users[i];    
    }
}       
    next();
}
```

but I don't know how to add the error part, and the `next()` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `Error` object and pass it to the `next` callback if the route parameter `:person` isn't found in the `users` array

```
function loadUser(req, res, next) {
    var person = req.params.person;
    for(var i= 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
      if ( person === users[i].name ) {
        req.user = users[i];
      }
    }
    if(!req.user) next(new Error('No such user ' + person));
    else next();
}
```

An error handler middleware in Connect, which Express uses, must take 4 arguments, that is, it must have an arity of 4. In fact, explicitly checking for an error using `if(err)` isn't required in the error handler middleware as Express invokes it only when an error occurs.

```
var sendInfo = function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.user.info);
}

app.get('/test/:person', loadUser, sendInfo, function(err, req, res, next) {
   if (err) {
      res.redirect('/');
   }
});
```

Comment: The redirect works now on invalid `:person`. However, when it's joe/betty, the page doesn't load.

Comment: Yes, the error handler middleware is only invoked when an error is passed to `next`. You must also attach another middleware that handles/serves valid users(`sendInfo`). I have edited my post to add `sendInfo`.

Comment: It's the same issue, invalid `:person` redirects work flawlessly, but pages with valid names fail to load; chrome stays stuck on load.

Comment: Invocation of `next` callback was missing for valid users. It should work now.